# Unable to push to docker registry in Artifactory with anonymous access disabled

Tags: docker, http-headers, authorization, artifactory

I created a local docker repository in Artifactory and enabled anonymous access following [this document](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories).

When I try and push a docker image it gives the following error:

```
unauthorized: The client does not have permission to push to the repository.
```

My docker version is 1.10 and the Artifactory version is 4.2.2.

I also tried forcing authentication but after docker login I get the same error (note that this error goes away after reloading nginx configuration and occurs again after a while).

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you ran into https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-7915. Upgrading to Artifactory 4.5.2 may fix it for you.

Answer (score -1):

Your version of Artifactory has a [bug with the push of a docker image](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingtotheLatestVersion) but  is solved in the 4.5.2 version. Update your Artifactory (it's a minor update).

You can update your Artifactory depending of your installation type(ZIP/RPM/RPM OSS/Debian/Docker).

[Here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-UpgradingtotheLatestVersion) you can find detailed instructions for each type:

- [ZIP installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-ZIPInstallation)
- [RPM installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-RPMInstallation)
- [RPM OSS installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-RPMOSSInstallation)
- [Debian installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-DebianInstallation)
- [Docker installation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Upgrading+Artifactory#UpgradingArtifactory-DockerInstallation)